# Reserving a Port number for exclusive use for our application

Tags: java, sockets

We have a software application which has a client-server architecture and will be only used over a LAN. Therefore, we intend to use Java Socket Programming in order to implement this (based on a clearly defined protocol).

We have two kinds of setups: *Server Setup* (Setting up of the server as background process listening on a port for requests) and a *Client Setup*. Both these can be invoked manually by the user depending on what he wants the software to behave as on that particular computer.

Now, in the case of the Server application, during the setup process, we specify certain details such as the Port number, etc... . So, what we want to do now is to ensure that once a port number is fixed on that machine, as long as the software application is present (and IRRESPECTIVE of server downtime or uptime), we want to make sure that no other third party application / product uses that port.

Currently, is there a way to do this through code (Java) ? Assume that this application need not always run as administrator and therefore may not have privileges to access the windows registry.

I hope that I have been clear with respect to the problem statement. Of course, in the event of any clarifications required, please do ask and I shall try to explain further.

Looking forward to suggestions on tacking this issue.

Comment: A port can only be reserved as long as there is a program running that has bound to that port. If your program stops running for some reason, then anyone else can use that port.

Comment: The closest I can think of is what `launchd` (and others) do in that they listen to a port for you and start your service on demand when something accesses that port. I don't really think the Windows service host offers this capability though. (Honestly, if you're making server software to be deployed on a LAN server, it's not unreasonable to expect the client to deal with assigning it a persistent port number.)

Answer (score 6):

you simply can't ...

when your program is down, any other program can open your port, and prevent your program from using it once it has started ...

Comment: +1 The only way to do this is to have the port used all the time, even if its small program which just holds the port open.

Answer (score 1):

One way around this is to use service discovery.  There are many ways to implement this.

What they in common is the ability to look up the service by name or id and connect to it regardless of the port actually used.  It could be different every time it is run. This way your application can use any free port and not need to reserve a port (or even only run on one host)

Answer (score 0):

You could give https://github.com/ProfessorEugene/PortReserve (java 1.6+) a try - full disclosure, I am the author.